# Motor shake and loud when accelerating

Tags: engine, chevrolet, noise, malibu

first post here. My car , Chevy Malibu 2005 LS 3.5L V6, recently started to be much more loud when accelerating. It shake a lot too. But only when accelerating and especially at 1000RPM. When don't move its smooth. But after some times, I heard a small pitch sound, like birds or grasshopper. So I suspected it was my water pump, but the pitched sound seems to be every now and then. So suspect it could be the exhaust. Any idea?

I hope I can repair it myself, because I don't really trust mechanics honesty. I got the car to two different mechanics last year, one said everything was okay for general inspection, the other said I got something with my brake oil.

Comment: I used an OBDII, and got no codes. I have no light on the dashboard.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

The exhaust system might be vibrating against the body structure of the car, particularly at 1000 rpm. Check the exhaust system hangers and rubber mounts for wear or fracture. You should make sure that the exhaust system can move, but cannot come in contact with the metal underside of the vehicle.

Note too that worn motor mounts might, at certain rpms, allow the engine to move sufficiently that the exhaust touches the body structure.

Answer (score 0):

Check the tension and condition of your belts as they might need replacing or adjusting. If you had a recording of the pitch, it would help us diagnose.